# dispatch con typescript

Tags: typescript

Trato de mandar este dispatch pero me trae este error(y todos mis otros dispatch tambien tienen el mismo problema):

Argument of type '(dispatch: Dispatch) => Promise' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Action'

```
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getTodos(findError));
  }, []);
```

Este seria mi action, en el cual se ejecuta el dispatch:

```
type Error = (err: null | string) => void

export const getTodos = (findError: Error) => {
  return async (dispatch: Dispatch<Action>): Promise<Action> => {
    try {
      findError(null);
      const response = await axios(`...`);
      const result: TodoItem[] = response.data;

      return dispatch({
        type: ActionTypes.GET_TODOS,
        payload: result,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      findError("Ha ocurrido un error al cargar las tareas");
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
};
```

y este seria el objeto Action que aparece en todo mi codigo:

```
import { TodoItem } from "types/interfaces/interfaces.actions";
import { ActionTypes } from "redux/actions-types";

export interface GetTodos {
  type: ActionTypes.GET_TODOS;
  payload: TodoItem[];
}

export interface DeleteTodo {
  type: ActionTypes.DELETE_TODO;
  payload: number | string;
}

export interface PutTodo{
  type: ActionTypes.PUT_TODO,
  payload: PutTodoData
}

interface PutTodoData {
  id: number | string;
  checked: boolean;
}

export interface PostTodo{
  type: ActionTypes.POST_TODO,
  payload: TodoItem
}

export interface OrderTodo{
  type: ActionTypes.ORDER_TODO,
  payload: TodoItem[]
}

export type Action = GetTodos | DeleteTodo | PutTodo | PostTodo | OrderTodo;
```

La verdad no tengo idea que podria ser, intente de todo, para hacer dispatch utilizo el useAppDispatch tambien. Y esta bien implementado.

Answer (score 0):

Revisa este return.

```
return dispatch({
    type: ActionTypes.GET_TODOS,
    payload: result,
  });
```

Terminas Llamamando a dispatch(dispatch{...}) y seguro que ahí hay algún error